# How to draw output resistance vs frequency in simulation?

Tags: bjt, orcad

I have a task to simulate this circuit and draw Rout vs frequency in the simulator. any idea how can I do this.
I am using OrCad
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Vs to zero (so it doesn't interfere with the AC plot) then inject a signal into the output via a suitably scaled resistor and coupling capacitor. The voltage at the output will drop as the output resistance drops and you can use this to estimate the output impedance of the circuit.